# Populating a two dimensional vector C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project for school to create a minesweeper game.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int mines;
int rows;
int columns;
vector<vector<int> > mineField; 

int main() {

    cout << "Input number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Input number of columns: ";
    cin >> columns;
    cout << "Input number of mines: ";
    cin >> mines;

    int mine = 0;
    int num_of_mines = 0;

    vector<int> temp; 

    while(num_of_mines < mines){

        mine = rand()%(rows * mines);

        if(mineField[mine][mine] != 1){

            temp.push_back(1);
            mineField.push_back(temp);
            num_of_mines++;

        }
    }

 return 0;   
}
```

What i'm trying to do here is populate the minefield using a two dimensional vector and then trying to output it to see if the mines were randomly allocated. (1 <=> mines); but this keeps giving me an error.
Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: What's your error? Also the `mines` is never initialised.

Comment: You need some loop to fill the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated, your problem is that you don't properly allocate your `mineField` matrix. Easiest would be to add

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    mineField.push_back(vector<int>(columns, 0)); // init everything to zeroes
}
```

Now you can populate the mine field with mines. Some pointers on generating mines: at the moment you only randomize one coordinate, but you should randomize two. Also, I'm not entirely sure why you need to multiply by `mines`. I would do something like:

```
while (num_of_mines < mines) {
    minex = rand() % columns;
    miney = rand() % rows;
    if (mineField[minex][miney] != 1)
        ...
```

Comment: When I initialize everything in the vector to zeroes, it works; but when I input a value for columns that is larger than the rows (for example: 16x30:99 mines) the run fails.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it. It was a mistake. I put the minex variable (the columns) where row was supposed to be. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @WilmerSuarez Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement looks after something that does not exist because of the way mine is computed (you look after the size of the matrix not after the size of a line and a column)

(you do not correctly init the minefield and do not use columns)